# VBA Array extract data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

When the "Not" in "And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic" is left out the code is able to pull italicized and underlined words but when I place a "Not" in the code to pull out the underlined and not italicized words it doesn't work. I'm not exactly sure why the "Not" wouldnt work. The pictures below are the source sheet and the new sheet with the extracted data. Im able to use the code to get underlined and italicized but I'm adding the Not so I can  get underlined but not italicized. The data that is supposed to come out is line 5 from the picture labeled 1.

[image]

[image]

```css
Sub extract()        
    Dim dataRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim marr As Variant
    
    Set dataRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C10")
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cl In dataRng
            marr = GetUnderlines(cl)
            If IsArray(marr) Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(marr) + 1) = Application.Transpose(marr)
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
Function GetUnderlines(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iEnd As Long, iIni As Long, strngLen As Long

    strngLen = Len(rng.Value2)
    iIni = 1
    
    Do While iEnd <= strngLen
        Do While rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic
            If iEnd = strngLen Then Exit Do
            iEnd = iEnd + 1
        Loop
        If iEnd > iIni Then strng = strng & Mid(rng.Value2, iIni, iEnd - iIni) & "|"
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
        iIni = iEnd
    Loop
    
    If strng <> "" Then GetUnderlines = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure as to your main question about why `Not` is being weird. ...but does it work as you expect if you replace that with `rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic = False`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes even when I try setting it False it brings the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Font.Underline` doesn't return a `Boolean(True/False)` ;) It returns an `Long`

If you add a `Watch` you can see it for yourself.

[image]

Change your code to

```
Do While rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle _
And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic
```

Comment: So it wasn't the `Not` acting funky, but the first part? And I'm surprised you can't get a boolean value from `.underline`, kind of counter intuitive since you can with italics/bold

Comment: with only `xlUnderlineStyleSingle` in the loop condition, any entry without without underline will get skipped, whether or not its italic.

Comment: @cyboashu: If my understanding is correct, OP wants to skip text which is not underlined

Comment: ah... OK,. he had first row in his expected data set, so i thought he is looking for w/o underlines too.:)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Change while condition to this :

Underline is not `boolean`.

```
 Do While (rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline = -4142 Or _
                 (rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline = 2 And _
                 Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is truncating the last character.

```
Function GetUnderlines(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iEnd As Long, iIni As Long, strngLen As Long

    strngLen = Len(rng.Value2)
    iIni = 1

    Do While iEnd <= strngLen
        Do While rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic And rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Text <> " "
            iEnd = iEnd + 1
            If iEnd > strngLen Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If iEnd > iIni Then
            strng = strng & Mid(rng.Value2, iIni, iEnd - iIni) & "|"

        End If
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
        iIni = iEnd
    Loop

    If strng <> "" Then GetUnderlines = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")

End Function
```